# shadow and shading

Tags: c, algorithm, graphics, pseudocode

I have read lots of ray tracer algorithm on the web. But, I have no clear understanding of the shading and shadow. Is below pseudocode correct written according to my understanding ?

```
for each primitive 
    check for intersection
    if there is one 
         do color be half of the background color
         Ishadow = true
         break

for each ambient light in environment        
    calculate light contribution to the color

if ( Ishadow == false ) 
   for each point light 
     calculate diffuse shading
     calculate reflection direction
     calculate specular light


trace for reflection ray // (i)  
add color returned from i after multiplied by some coefficient

trace for refraction ray // (ii)
add color returned from ii after multiplied by some coefficient

return color value calculated until this point
```

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate your shadows with the normal ray-tracing path:
For every screen-pixel you send a ray through the scene and you eventually determine the closest object-intersection: at the point of the closest object-intersection you would at first read out the pixel color (texture of the object at that point), aside from calculating reflection-vector etc (using the normal-vector) you would now **additionally** cast a ray from that intersection-point to each of the light-sources in your scene: if these rays intersect other objects before hitting the light-sources then the intersection-point is in shadow and you can adapt the final color of that point accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with pseudocode is that it is easy to get "pseudo" enough that it becomes the same well of ambiguity that we are trying to avoid by getting away from natural languages.  "Color be half of the background color?"  The fact that this line appears before you iterate through your light sources is confusing.  How can you be setting Ishadow before you iterate over light sources?

Maybe a better description would be:

```
given a ray in space
    find nearest object with which ray intersects
    for each point light
        if normal at surface of intersected object points toward light (use dot product for this)
            cast a ray into space from the surface toward the light
                if ray intersection is closer than light* light is shadowed at this point
```

*If you're seeing strange artifacts in your shadows, there is a mistake that is made by every single programmer when they write their first ray tracer.  Floating point (or double-precision) math is imprecise and you will frequently (about half the time) re-intersect yourself when doing a shadow trace.  The explanation is a bit hard to describe without diagrams, but let me see what I can do.

If you have an intersection point on the surface of a sphere, under most circumstances, that point's representation in a floating point register is not mathematically exact.  It is either slightly inside or slightly outside the sphere.  If it is inside the sphere and you try to run an intersection test to a light source, the nearest intersection will be the sphere itself.  The intersection distance will be very small, so you can simply reject any shadow ray intersection that is closer than, say .000001 units.  If your geometry is all convex and incapable of legitimately shadowing itself, then you can simply skip testing the sphere when doing shadow tests.

Comment: Where you would normally do "if distance between ray origin and intersection is less than distance to light," you would simply expand it to "if distance between ray origin and intersection is less than distance to light AND distance is greater than .00001, then point is shadowed."